# Spring auto populate list with mocks

Tags: spring, unit-testing, auto-populate

I would like to know if anybody has successfully @Autowired an auto-populated *list* of objects, injecting mocks, with Spring during the test phase of the build? What I want to be able to do is *override* Spring's auto-population of a list during test time and have it populated with mocks within a unit test, instead of the implementation classes. I have successfully accomplished this by specifying @Resource within the code instead of @Autowired, but then when I deploy the Spring web app, the auto-population does not execute with @Resource specified for my list (it's just empty). The oppposite happens when I specify @Autowired on the list. The list is auto-populated when the app runs, but then I cannot populate the list with mocks when the unit tests run. It seems to be a catch-22...

So how do I use @Resource on a List type and have Spring still do the auto-population at runtime? Has anybody done this successfully - use auto-population at runtime, but substitute mocks into the list during the test phase? If so, could you possibly post relevant parts of your test @Configuration class? (Java annotations please, not XML). Thanks..

This works for injecting mocks, but then auto-population of the list doesn't kick in at runtime:

```
@Resource(name = "myServices")
private List<MyService> myServices;
```

And in my test config:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("myServices")
public List<MyService> myServices() {
    List<MyService> myServices = new ArrayList<>();
    MyService mockService1 = Mockito.mock(MyService.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    MyService mockService2 = Mockito.mock(MyService.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    eventServices.add(mockService1);
    eventServices.add(mockService2);
    return myServices;
}
```

And then with the following, auto-population is active all the time (at runtime and during the test phase), but I cannot override and inject the mocks during the test phase with @Autowired, as it ignores the myServices @Bean definition from the test config:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myServices")
private List<MyService> myServices;
```

Thanks in advance for any insight on this.

Comment: Is just using constructor injection an option? It's usually the easiest way to handle mock injection.

Comment: Thanks for the response... Are you saying that I should auto wire the list into the service class's ctor? I can try that. I was just wondering why the auto-population doesn't work with the resource annotation but it does with autowired though

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but these days I usually just avoid the issue entirely and use the constructor.

Comment: I actually get the same error via ctor injection: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.List]: : No qualifying bean of type [com.mycompany.MyService] found for dependency expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: Just to clarify - the @Autowired behavior on the ctor produces the same problem as the setter injection, which is that I still can't inject the mocks at test time. The auto-population of the implementation classes via ctor works, but the tests fail because the bean definition for the list inside the test harness config is still ignored.